# Merge() in multithreaded JPA application

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa

i have an application with a gui and a list of stocks that are saved in a db. I use 1 EntityManager the whole time the app is running, for deleting, changing and adding new stocks. I have a thread that periodically grabs the actual stock courses of the stocks and saves them in the db. I use another entity manager in the thread (cause of thread safety).

That means for every operation i do on a stock (like deleting, changing, viewing stock courses) i have to call merge first, cause the main entity manager doesn't know the stock courses the other has added. The problem now is that if the program has run for a long time and the user has never done anything with a stock, there will be thousands of new courses that need to merge first, thus taking a very long time (> 10 seconds). What can i do about this? Or am i doing it wrong and there is a better way?

Edit: That's basically what i do each 5 minutes in my thread:

```
    // grabbing the actual stockprice and making actualStockPrice with it
....
    // adding the correct stock to the new stockprice
actualStockPrice.setStock(stock);
   // adding stockprice to stock
stock.getActualStockPrices().add(actualStockPrice);
   // Saving new price to db (stockPriceModel has it's own em)
 stockPriceModel.saveActualStockPrice(actualStockPrice);
```

saveActualStockPrice in stockPriceModel:

```
transaction.commit();
transaction.begin();
em.persist(actualStockPrice);
```

Cause i use a different entitymanager in my thread then in the rest of my application i now have data (namely all stockPrices that the thread saved in the db) in my db my main em doesn't know i have to call merge() before i do anything with the data. If i don't do that my em tries to insert the new StockPrices again as soon as i commit() something with it. The problem is now that i if i don't commit something for a long time there will be so much detached stockPrices (say a few 1000) that the merge() will take an eternity. And now i have no idea what to do.

Comment: please post code examples to illustrate your entity model, along with which statement is the slow one and some example SQL queries that result

Answer (score 0):

I am having to guess a bit what you want, but I will try.  One problem I have is that I do not know what a "stock course" is; I am assuming it is some collection of information about a stock.

If I read you correctly, you have some set of information about a set of stocks, and every so often you go and get updated information.  For some reason you do not update the stock information you had originally until the user does something.  I am guessing this is where your problem is.

I suggest updating your original set of information with new information as soon as you get the new information.  This should be possible by synchronizing your threads on the objects that update the information.  For instance, just as an example, if you had a class that represented all the information for one stock, and it had methods to persist current values to the database, you could synchronize access to those methods to ensure that no two threads attempted to update the information at the same time, and thereby would avoid any problems of two methods cross-updating information.

I'm surprised your UI doesn't get the updates as soon as you do them; perhaps it does but your database does not.  As I say, it is difficult to understand exactly what you're doing with the program from your current description.

Comment: The stockCourses are the stockPrices sry i used 2 words for the same :/ Basically the gui is a list of stocks (name, etc) and each stock in the list is updated every 5 minutes with the newly grabbed Stockprice. My code in my 1st post does this (it adds the newly grabbed stock price to the appropiate stock and the appropiate stock to the new stock price object and then saves the newly stock price to the db). My problem now is that i have 2 entity managers.

Comment: The one in the thread that writes the actual stock prices in the table and the other one that does everything else in the app. When i now commit anything with my main em it tries to also save the new stockprice in the db cause the new stockprices are in the model but my main em thinks they aren't in the db, cause he never commited them. That's why i have to use merge before commit so that he get's the new stockprices and doesn't try to add them again. But if the user for a long time doesn't do anything there will be a lot of new stockprices and thus the next commit (merge) will take "forever".

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot figure out what you're trying to say.  "writes the actual stock prices in the table" - db table or JTable?  or some other table?  "does everything else" - what?  "Main em" - which one is that?  "cause he never committed them" - he who?  why not?  "...so that he get's" - he who?  "there will be a lot of new stock prices" where?  you have a thread writing them to the model and the database, where are they stacking up?  Why DO you have two entity managers?  I think it is time to take 3 steps back and describe what you are trying to do at a high level.  Separate that

Comment: from what your implementation does now.  I *think* you are using an implementation that doesn't fit what you want to do, and instead of changing your implementation, you're trying to 'fix' this one.  But I cannot tell, because you don't describe what you want from the beginning, you start in the middle and assume I understand things already.